# How to get the sulution values for Pyomo named expressions?

Tags: expression, pyomo

I defined a abstract pyomo model using named expressions (see "m.ElecDemand_kW" in the code below).
I wonder how to get the solution value for [named expressions.](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developer_reference/expressions/design.html#special-expression-classes) They are also called [Expression Objects.](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_modeling_components/Expressions.html#expression-objects)

```
from pyomo.environ import *
m = AbstractModel('TEST')

...
code
...

def Epr_elecDemand_kW_rule(m, b, sv, ts):
    return (sum(m.Elec_Heater_kW_elec[b, sv, em, ts] for em in m.ELEC_HeaterModes)
                                  + sum(m.Hp_kW_elec[b, sv, hm, ts] for hm in m.HP_ALL))

m.ElecDemand_kW= Expression(m.BUILDtype, m.STOR_LiterVar, m.TS, rule=Epr_elecDemand_kW_rule)


def Obj_Funct_rule(m):
    return sum(m.ElecDemand_kW[b, sv,ts] * m.t_step_seconds[ts] / 3600 / 1000 * m.ts_data["spotPrice_EpMWh",ts]
            for b in m.BUILDtype
            for sv in m.STOR_LiterVar
            for ts in m.TS)

m.ObjectFunction = Objective(rule=Obj_Funct_rule)

instance = m.create_instance('GebaeudeV8.dat')
opt_results = opt.solve(instance, symbolic_solver_labels=True, keepfiles = True,
                        tee=True)  
instance.solutions.store_to(opt_results)
```

At the moment I define after the solve command a new function

```
def Epr_elecDemand_kW_calc(m, b, sv, ts):
    return (sum(instance.Elec_Heater_kW_elec[b, sv, em, ts].value 
                     for em in instance.ELEC_HeaterModes.data())
           + sum(instance.Hp_kW_elec[b, sv, hm, ts] 
                    for hm in instance.HP_ALL.data()))
```

to calculate the desired solution values and then copy it to a pandas dataframe and save it to Excel.
It there a easy way to get the sulution values of named expressions after solving the problem?

I just found out that `value(Epr_elecDemand_kW_rule(instance, b, sv, ts))`
works

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use the `value` function on the Expression component itself instead of the rule:

```
value(instance.ElecDemand_kw[i,j,k])
```